# Use substr() in array without loop?

Tags: php, arrays, substr

Is there any way to use substr() function on all of an array's elements without using a loop?

Comment: what do u want to get exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Looping is sometimes the most simple and readable solution.  But if you want to apply a function to every element of an array you can also use array_map.

Here an anonymous function is a simple wrapper for substr, which is used to return the first letter of each name in the given array:

```
<?php

$names =
[
    'Gaga',
    'Joplin',
    'Vega'    
];

$first_letters = 
    array_map(
        function($str) { return substr($str, 0, 1); },
        $names
    );

var_export($first_letters);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'G',
    1 => 'J',
    2 => 'V',
  )
```

Short arrow functions introduced in Php 7.4. are slightly tidier:

```
array_map(
    fn($str) => substr($str, 0, 1),
    $names
);
```

The foreach/loop approach:

```
foreach($names as $key => $name)
    $result[$key] = substr($name, 0, 1);
```

Mutating the original array:

```
foreach($names as &$name)
    $name = substr($name, 0, 1);
unset($name);
```